# Substitute bitwise in hexToRgba conversion

Tags: typescript

I am trying to implement the following function which converts hex into rgba:

```
  static hexToRgbA(hex: string): string {
    let c;
    if (hex.charAt(0) === '#') {
      if (/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(hex)) {
        c = hex.substring(1).split('');
        if (c.length === 3) {
          c = [c[0], c[0], c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2]];
        }
        c = '0x' + c.join('');
        return (
          'rgba(' + [(c >> 16) & 255, (c >> 8) & 255, c & 255].join(',') + ',1)'
        );
      }
    } else {
      return hex;
    }
  }
```

However at the following line, I get the ESLint error: `ESLint: Unexpected use of '>>'.(no-bitwise)`. How do I fix this

```
'rgba(' + [(c >> 16) & 255, (c >> 8) & 255, c & 255].join(',') + ',1)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linter rule is to avoid accidentally using bitwise operators like `&` and `>>` when `&&` and `>` are intended. You can disable the rule in your eslint configuration, or make it less strict by specifying operators you don't want it to flag (see [no-bitwise documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-bitwise)). But you can also just disable it only for this line:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-bitwise
return 'rgba(' + [(c >> 16) & 255, (c >> 8) & 255, c & 255].join(',') + ',1)';
```

Note that the comment is line based, so if you use multiple lines for the return statement you'll have to do

```
return (
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-bitwise
  'rgba(' + [(c >> 16) & 255, (c >> 8) & 255, c & 255].join(',') + ',1)'
);
```